# CMI at 20 conference

Tags: soft-question, conferences

Just recently (September 24 - 26) there was a conference at Oxford dedicated to 20th anniversary of CMI. (https://www.claymath.org/events/cmi-20) The program looks interesting. Does anyone know if there will be videos (or, at least, proceedings) published?

Comment: The organizers of the conference certainly do. Why not simply write an email to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the lectures were filmed, so I have to figure they will be putting them online at some point.